# Why won't Xcode compile the dictionary creation line?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, syntax

Xcode won't compile the creation of the dictionary, must i update anything or is there something that i am missing?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var dictionary: [String:Int]()
```

Comment: `var dictionary = [String: Int]()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have combined a type declaration (the colon) and a call to initializer (the empty parentheses after the type).

If you would like to keep the explicit type, you could do it like this:

```
var dictionary: [String:Int] = [String:Int]()
```

However, specifying the type is not necessary, because Swift figures out the type for you. This declaration is identical, but takes less space:

```
var dictionary = [String:Int]()
```